# How can I create a notification count with layered Segoe MDL2 Assets font / icons

Tags: c#, xaml, fonts, layer

I'm trying to make a toolbar using the "Segoe MDL2 Assets" Icons.
[image: Favorites/Notification Toolbar]

MS recommends not using the older Segoe UI Symbol font since it is now Legacy.  What I want is XAML or C# that places single characters of this font on top of one another or a character on top of an icon.  Centered would be okay, but I really want to positioned them relative to one another.

[Segoe MDL2 Assets Icons guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font) mentions layering / stacking these icons / characters used to be supported, but doesn't indicate how it should be done now.

It would be very useful for displaying notifications like VS2015 has, the inbox messages here, or a numbered favorite list with a number inside of a heart, star, circle or square.

My current solution is using a grid with two TextBlocks or a TextBlock and a Rectangle.  It's close, but not exactly what I want.  Does someone have a better way stacking or overlaying them?

```
<ToolBarTray>
    <ToolBar x:Name="WindowsTools" OverflowMode="Never" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True" Loaded="ToolBar_Loaded">
        <Button x:Name="Favorite_1" ToolTip="Favorite 1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="20" Click="Favorite_Click" Tag="1">
            <Grid>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center">
                    <Run FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets">&#xE006;</Run>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Red">
                    <Run FontSize="8" FontFamily="Segoe WP" Typography.Variants="Superscript">&#x277A;</Run>
            </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="Favorite_2" ToolTip="Favorite 2" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="20" Click="Favorite_Click" Tag="2">
            <Grid>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center">
                    <Run FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets">&#xE7C1;</Run>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="Blue">
                    <Run FontSize="8" FontFamily="Segoe WP" Typography.Variants="Superscript">&#x2778;</Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="Notifications" ToolTip="Notifications" Click="Notification_Click" Tag="Users">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center">
                    <Run FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets">&#xE716;</Run>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="Purple">
                    <Run FontSize="8" FontFamily="Segoe WP" Typography.Variants="Superscript">&#x2779;</Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="Alerts" ToolTip="Alerts" Click="Alerts_Click" Tag="Users">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center">
                    <Run FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets">&#xE715;</Run>
                </TextBlock>
                <Rectangle Width="12" Height="8" Fill="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White">
                    <Run FontSize="7" FontFamily="Courier New" FontWeight="Bold" Text=" 2 "></Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, the documentation you pointed to is describing layering that already exists in the font for colorizing glyphs. Clients/users do not normally define layering, and normally (under systems that support color font rendering) don't need to do anything special to use them.

Some additional backround: beyond normal glyph data (in a 'glyf' table), the font contains color palette ('CPAL') and layering ('COLR') tables that are effectively "recipes" for colorized glyphs. The 'COLR' table defines the layers by referencing glyphIDs in the 'glyf' table and RGBA colors via indexes into the 'CPAL' table. Systems that understand the 'COLR' and 'CPAL' tables will use the recipes to build up a colorized glyph out of the defined layers. On systems that do not support color rendering with COLR/CPAL, the standard "fallback" monochrome glyphs will be shown instead.

So if you are just using the font in an app, web page, etc., you don't really have to do anything special. If you are using the font on a system where colorization is not supported, and you wish to have color support, you will need to parse the [COLR](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/COLR.htm) and [CPAL](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/CPAL.htm) tables and use those to render the text with color.